# How to zoom in and out JPanel in java?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

i want zoom in and out JPanel .. i made some of code but i can't complete it 
and this is what i made and center_panel is the panel which i want to zoom

```
@Override
protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
    g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_INTERPOLATION,
            RenderingHints.VALUE_INTERPOLATION_BICUBIC);
    double x = (getWidth() - scale*center_panel.getWidth())/2;
    double y = (getHeight() - scale*center_panel.getHeight())/2;
    AffineTransform at = AffineTransform.getTranslateInstance(x,y);
    at.scale(scale, scale);
}
```

Comment: You could refer to this question: [Zoom in and out of jPanel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33925884/zoom-in-and-out-of-jpanel)

Comment: i saw this question before but it doesn't clear for me like variable mydrawer i don't know if it JPanel or another something and ZoomFactor i don't know what is it refers to ?

Comment: Creating a zoomed **image** of a panel is fairly easy, but it is much harder if it's necessary to actually interact with the controls in the panel. Which is it you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Making it possible to interact with a panel like this is rather tricky. And similar questions are asked frequently. I once created a small library for that, under https://github.com/javagl/Viewer (available in Maven Central), but of course, one could imagine arbitrary extensions to that.